# Post Apocalyptic movie, beginning has a guy playing a trumpet overlooking a city

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

Cannot remember any details other than a post apocalyptic style, a dilapidated city, and a guy playing a trumpet.

Live action movie, possibly has some kids living in the city the protagonist helps...

Probably 1980's or early 90's.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there are a lot of details you could add. I suggest you take a tour of the site... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: If this was animated a strong contender could be Laputa, Castle In the Sky from Studio Gibli. Early on it does feature a prominent scene with a character playing a trumpet over the ruins of a building at dawn, the setting is post apocalyptic and the time frame would match as this was made in 1986. Here is a still image, sorry can't find the actual clip... if I do I'll put it up, more details would really help us.

Comment: thanks for that extra detail. Live action rules out Laputa. I didn't think it would be that easy!

Comment: It couldn't possibly be _Young Frankenstein_, even If the trumpet were actually at the end......?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Made an account just to answer this!

It's called *[2019, After the Fall of New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019,_After_the_Fall_of_New_York)*

Love this movie.

It's got Snake Plisskin lite in a *Children of Men* story with a Sleeping Beauty. A little vehicular warfare for good measure.

I highly recommend *Salute Of The Juggers* just because I love that post-apoc flick too.

### Trailer

[Intro with guy with trumpet](https://vimeo.com/157080940)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you add any details about the trumpet-playing guy?  (His name, or role?)  Where do the kids fit in?

Comment: He doesn't help any kids. He does help a midget though.

Comment: Oh my god that's the movie! Thank you so much.